# Delete button is not working, blank page returned

Tags: php, html

My delete button is not working.

For a view file it's working - this is my code for **view_file.php**:

```html
<?php
$sql_id="SELECT * FROM meeting_info where id=".$id ;
`$result2 = $conn->query($sql_id);
if($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
$bilno = $row2['bilno'];
}
?>

  <body>
    <div id="body">
      <table align="center" width="90%">
        <tr>
          <th colspan="6">
            <div align="center">
              <h3>Meeting Bil.No
                <?php echo $bilno; ?> </h3>
            </div>
          </th>
        </tr>
        <tr bgcolor="#3366ff">
          <td>Bil. Item</td>
          <td>File Type</td>
          <td>File Size (KB)</td>
          <td>View</td>
          <td>Edit</td>
          <td>Delete</td>
        </tr>
        <?php
$sql="SELECT * FROM meeting_details where id=".$id ." order by item_no asc";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
{
    if($j%2 == 1) {$colortd = "#99ccff";
}
 else  {$colortd = "#f5f5f0";}   
?>
          <tr bgcolor=<?php echo $colortd;?>>
            <td>
              <?php echo $row['item_no'] ?>
            </td>
            <td>
              <?php echo $row['type'] ?>
            </td>
            <td>
              <?php echo $row['size'] ?>
            </td>
            <td>
              <a class="btn btn-view" href="uploads/<?php echo $row['file']; ?>" target="_blank" alt="<?php echo $row['item_no']; ?>" title="click for edit">
                <center><img src="images\iconview.png"></center>
              </a>
            </td>
            <td>
              <a class="btn btn-info" href="edit_file.php?edit=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" title="click for edit" onclick="return confirm('sure to edit ?')">
                <center><img src="images\iconedit.png"></center>
            </td>
            <td>
              <a class="btn btn-danger" href="delete_file.php?delete=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" title="click for delete" onclick="return confirm('sure to delete ?')">
                <center><img src="images\icondel.png"></center>
            </td>

          </tr>
          <?php
  $j++;
 }
 //$conn->close();
 ?>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
```

For the delete button, I want to delete all rows on information that I want to delete. But it's not working. When i click the delete button it's just come out the blank page. The data still have in database and website.

This my **delete_file.php** code:

```html
<?php 
  include("db_conn.php");  
if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id']))
{  
 $id =$_GET['id']; 
 $sql = "DELETE FROM meeting_details WHERE id=".$id; 
 $result = $conn->query($sql);
 
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Any error appearing?

Comment: (1) Your code is wide open to SQL injection.  (2) You're not checking for errors after executing your SQL commands.  When you debug, where/how specifically is this failing?  Is the `DELETE` command being executed?  Is the database returning an error?

Comment: there is no error appearing. database not returning error.

Comment: There's an error of undefined index id

Comment: What will happen with your code `"DELETE FROM meeting_details WHERE id=".$id`, when someone submits an `id` value like `1 OR id IS NOT NULL`?

Answer (score 0):

Check this line:

```
<a class="btn btn-danger" href="delete_file.php?delete=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" title="click for delete" onclick="return confirm('sure to delete ?')">
```

here the delete url is like: `delete_file.php?delete=1` and you are fetching the value like:

```
$id =$_GET['id'];
```

So change it to:

```
$id =$_GET['delete'];
```

and try again.

**Note: Your code is wide open to SQL injection**

Comment: i already done change it but it still the same. i will try to do it again. maybe there something i miss.